# Docker for Windows - Cannot list nodes: Get https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/api/v1/nodes: Forbidden

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I try to run Kubernetes from Docker for Windows. After I click on `Enable Kubernetes` inside the **Kubernetes** Tab the `Kuberneters is starting...` process running into a endless state.

Take look in the `service.txt` log in `C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\pki`, Docker repeat the following log-block for the whole time.

```
[10:23:26.068][ApiProxy          ][Error  ] time="2020-01-14T10:23:26+01:00" msg="Cannot list nodes: Get https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/api/v1/nodes: Forbidden"
[10:23:27.080][ApiProxy          ][Error  ] time="2020-01-14T10:23:27+01:00" msg="Cannot list nodes: Get https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/api/v1/nodes: Forbidden"
[10:23:28.071][ApiProxy          ][Error  ] time="2020-01-14T10:23:28+01:00" msg="Cannot list nodes: Get https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/api/v1/nodes: Forbidden"
[10:23:28.624][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] time="2020-01-14T10:23:28+01:00" msg="DNS failure: www-cache.\tIN\t A: errno 9002: DnsQuery: DNS-Serverfehler."
[10:23:28.626][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] time="2020-01-14T10:23:28+01:00" msg="DNS failure: www-cache.\tIN\t AAAA: errno 9002: DnsQuery: DNS-Serverfehler."
[10:23:29.068][ApiProxy          ][Error  ] time="2020-01-14T10:23:29+01:00" msg="Cannot list nodes: Get https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/api/v1/nodes: Forbidden"
[10:23:30.083][ApiProxy          ][Error  ] time="2020-01-14T10:23:30+01:00" msg="Cannot list nodes: Get https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/api/v1/nodes: Forbidden"
[10:23:31.088][ApiProxy          ][Error  ] time="2020-01-14T10:23:31+01:00" msg="Cannot list nodes: Get https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/api/v1/nodes: Forbidden"
[10:23:32.068][ApiProxy          ][Error  ] time="2020-01-14T10:23:32+01:00" msg="Cannot list nodes: Get https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/api/v1/nodes: Forbidden"
[10:23:32.715][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] time="2020-01-14T10:23:32+01:00" msg="DNS failure: www-cache.\tIN\t AAAA: errno 9002: DnsQuery: DNS-Serverfehler."
[10:23:32.717][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] time="2020-01-14T10:23:32+01:00" msg="DNS failure: www-cache.\tIN\t A: errno 9002: DnsQuery: DNS-Serverfehler."
[10:23:33.068][ApiProxy          ][Error  ] time="2020-01-14T10:23:33+01:00" msg="Cannot list nodes: Get https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/api/v1/nodes: Forbidden"
[10:23:34.074][ApiProxy          ][Error  ] time="2020-01-14T10:23:34+01:00" msg="Cannot list nodes: Get https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/api/v1/nodes: Forbidden"
[10:23:34.658][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] time="2020-01-14T10:23:34+01:00" msg="DNS failure: www-cache.\tIN\t A: errno 9002: DnsQuery: DNS-Serverfehler."
[10:23:34.661][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] time="2020-01-14T10:23:34+01:00" msg="DNS failure: www-cache.\tIN\t AAAA: errno 9002: DnsQuery: DNS-Serverfehler."
[10:23:35.069][ApiProxy          ][Error  ] time="2020-01-14T10:23:35+01:00" msg="Cannot list nodes: Get https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/api/v1/nodes: Forbidden"
[10:23:36.074][ApiProxy          ][Error  ] time="2020-01-14T10:23:36+01:00" msg="Cannot list nodes: Get https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/api/v1/nodes: Forbidden"
[10:23:37.070][ApiProxy          ][Error  ] time="2020-01-14T10:23:37+01:00" msg="Cannot list nodes: Get https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/api/v1/nodes: Forbidden"
[10:23:38.072][ApiProxy          ][Error  ] time="2020-01-14T10:23:38+01:00" msg="Cannot list nodes: Get https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/api/v1/nodes: Forbidden"
[10:23:39.072][ApiProxy          ][Error  ] time="2020-01-14T10:23:39+01:00" msg="Cannot list nodes: Get https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/api/v1/nodes: Forbidden"
[10:23:39.681][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] time="2020-01-14T10:23:39+01:00" msg="DNS failure: www-cache.\tIN\t AAAA: errno 9002: DnsQuery: DNS-Serverfehler."
[10:23:39.684][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] time="2020-01-14T10:23:39+01:00" msg="DNS failure: www-cache.\tIN\t A: errno 9002: DnsQuery: DNS-Serverfehler."
[10:23:40.069][ApiProxy          ][Error  ] time="2020-01-14T10:23:40+01:00" msg="Cannot list nodes: Get https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/api/v1/nodes: Forbidden"
[10:23:41.076][ApiProxy          ][Error  ] time="2020-01-14T10:23:41+01:00" msg="Cannot list nodes: Get https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/api/v1/nodes: Forbidden"
[10:23:42.089][ApiProxy          ][Error  ] time="2020-01-14T10:23:42+01:00" msg="Cannot list nodes: Get https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/api/v1/nodes: Forbidden"
[10:23:42.745][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] time="2020-01-14T10:23:42+01:00" msg="DNS failure: www-cache.\tIN\t A: errno 9002: DnsQuery: DNS-Serverfehler."
[10:23:42.748][ApiProxy          ][Info   ] time="2020-01-14T10:23:42+01:00" msg="DNS failure: www-cache.\tIN\t AAAA: errno 9002: DnsQuery: DNS-Serverfehler."
[10:23:43.071][ApiProxy          ][Error  ] time="2020-01-14T10:23:43+01:00" msg="Cannot list nodes: Get https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/api/v1/nodes: Forbidden"
[10:23:44.088][ApiProxy          ][Error  ] time="2020-01-14T10:23:44+01:00" msg="Cannot list nodes: Get https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/api/v1/nodes: Forbidden"
[10:23:44.758][VpnKit            ][Info   ] vpnkit.exe: Expired 256 UDP NAT rules
```

---

### Trouble Shooting:

#### Proxy-Settings

my machine is behind a proxy so I add the corresponding informations inside the **Proxy** tab

> No changes

#### Ping kubernetes.docker.internal

```
Ping wird ausgeführt für kubernetes.docker.internal [127.0.0.1] mit 32 Bytes Daten:
Antwort von 127.0.0.1: Bytes=32 Zeit<1ms TTL=128
Antwort von 127.0.0.1: Bytes=32 Zeit<1ms TTL=128
Antwort von 127.0.0.1: Bytes=32 Zeit<1ms TTL=128
Antwort von 127.0.0.1: Bytes=32 Zeit<1ms TTL=128
Ping-Statistik für 127.0.0.1:
    Pakete: Gesendet = 4, Empfangen = 4, Verloren = 0
```

#### Proxy: Ignore Local Address

Therefore kubernetes.docker.internal is a local address I add the address to the proxy ignoring list in docker and in my machine internetoptions.

> No changes

#### Install ca.crt from C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\pki

I also try to add the docker `.crt` to the trusted certificates of my machine

> No changes

#### Remove PKI and Reset Kubernetes Cluster

the endless state of starting kubernetes is not rare, so I found a lot suggestions to handle on [github](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2990). The most working suggestions are about remove stuff and reseting docker. I try all of them multiple times.

> No changes

#### Call `https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/api/v1/nodes` in Browser

[image]

---

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.5
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.12
 Git commit:        633a0ea
 Built:             Wed Nov 13 07:22:37 2019
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false
```

Testing on a Windows 10 Machine.

---

I spread all my shots and no more clue what to do.

Comment: Did you manage to solve problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem and it seems, that the k8s API doesn't want to answer to the TLS Client hello message. I checked the traffic with Wireshark on the [local interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9sPq.png) (this is the one used for kubernetes.docker.internal). The TCP session setup is working properly.

I also checked in the "Show system containers (advanced)" option in the docker for windows settings under the kubernetes tab, but the "docker ps -a" does not show up any container (I'm not sure it should, but the option's name suggest that to me).

I would gladly continue the debugging and see whether the API service is actually running in the HyperV virtual machine that provides docker in Windows, but I'm not able to connect to it through the Hyper-V Manager. Any idea, how to check that and get the logs for the service?

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to get K8s up when Windows Firewall fully OFF AND connected to a home network. Booting Docker & K8s while connected to the corporate network causes it to hang again at "Kubernetes is starting..."

**Another solution**

**1.** Change DNS to fixed and use 8.8.8.8, this is within docker for
    window's settings

**2.** Remove the .kube

**3.** Add the KUBECONFIG environment variable to System Variables and have
    the path be C:\Users[MYUSER].kube\config. Note that before I had
    it set as a User Variable.

**4.** Restart Docker from the Docker for Window's reset tab in settings.

**5.** Restart Kubernetes Cluster from the Docker for Window's reset tab in
    settings (you can do this a number of times).

Afterwards just wait for some time and Kubernetes is running should display

Take a look here: [kubernetes-fails-to-start](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1962).

I hope it helps.

Comment: thank you for your response. I follow your instruction. I disable my firewall and execute the 5 steps. Unfortunately the log still shows `"Cannot list nodes: Get https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/api/v1/nodes: Forbidden"`.